# Search for text in file stored using gridfs in mongo

Tags: mongodb

Search for text in file stored in mongo.
i want to search text in content which store in file using gridfs .
text as well as metadata of that file that search possible in mongoDB ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10491348/full-text-search-on-mongodb-gridfs

Comment: `Elasticsearch` may suit your use case better.